# Debug symbols stability

Tags: c++, c, debugging, standards, coredump

I am compiling an application with `-g` option:

```
gcc -g -o main1 main.c
```

then I strip debug object from it:

```
objcopy --strip-debug main1
```

Let's assume that my `main1` application will crash and I would like to use a core dump `coredump1` to debug the problem.

Could I rebuild the source code once more

```
gcc -g -o main2 main.c
```

and extract debug symbols

```
objcopy --only-keep-debug main2 main2.debug
```

and use `main2.debug` to debug the `coredump1`?

Can I trust that debug symbols will be always aligned? Is it guaranteed by language standard or compiler requirement?

Will debug symbols match if my source code will contain strings based on macros like`__DATE__` or `__TIME__` ?

Will it work if I enable code optimization?

Comment: Even if it would, don't bet your business/reputation/income/... on it. Every time you distribute your binary, keep a copy of the matching debug symbols. You can correlate them later by the build ID embedded in the program.

Comment: If main.c for main2 is different from main.c for main1, there is no guarantee that anything is aligned. As a result, you need either to keep a debug copy of main1, or have a real way to reproduce the main1 build from the same source with the same qualifiers. As for `__DATE__ `and `__TIME__` they should produce strings in the same format despite the real date and time. so, they should not affect debugging info.

Comment: If you are shipping programs - then you should keep a copy of the shipping executable with matching debug symbols (release version) and tag / label the source in your source code control system.  Nothing in the Standard or tool-chain docs guarantees that you can always exactly rebuild.  People jump through hoops getting automatic build systems to produce identical result (timestamps are one source of problems).

Comment: @Serge Maybe I didn't express it clearly enough, but the asumptom is that in both compilaiton I use exaclty the same `main.c` file.
So the quesiton can be rephresed in the following form - can I trust that in each compilation of the same source file it will always generate identical debug symbols. Bases on answers from Botje and Richard Critten I conclude that such assumption would be incorrect.

Comment: as soon as your timestamps produce strings of the same lengths and do not affect sizes of declared static variables, provided that you use the same version of gcc, same qualifiers and the same version of OS, you have a good chance to get the same compilation/debug results.

Comment: Follow up - if you plan to recompile to get matching code and symbols then you need to archive the complete tool-chain when you ship product (if you update anything the chance of matching code/symbols will be very very low).  This is more work that my recommendation above.

Answer (score 0):

> Will debug symbols match ...
> Will it work if I enable code optimizaiton?

As others have commented, you should not rely on this, and instead always build with `-g` and separate debug symbols out before shipping the "final product".

That said, in practice this *works* for GCC<sup>1</sup> with or without optimization, but doesn't work at all for Clang/LLVM (which gives you a practical reason not to depend on this).

---

<sup>1</sup> Or at least it did last time I tried this for several non-trivial binaries a few years ago.

Note that maintaining this property requires *active* effort from the compiler developers and thus can be broken as violations are introduced, noticed and fixed.